# In Rust, is a vector an Iterator?

Tags: iterator, rust

Is it accurate to state that a vector (among other collection types) is an `Iterator`?

For example, I can loop over a vector in the following way, because it implements the `Iterator` trait (as I understand it):

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for x in &v {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

However, if I want to use functions that are part of the `Iterator` trait (such as `fold`, `map` or `filter`) why must I first call `iter()` on that vector?

Another thought I had was maybe that a vector can be converted into an `Iterator`, and, in that case, the syntax above makes more sense.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/iterators.html says some stuff about `for x in &v` vs. `for x in v.iter()`, which is also valid.  I don't know Rust (yet) so I can't actually explain or summarize it, though!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

No, a vector is not an iterator.

But it implements the trait [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), which the `for` loop uses to convert the vector into the required iterator.

In the [documentation for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) you can see that `IntoIterator` is implemented in three ways:

- for `Vec<T>`, which is moved and the iterator returns items of type `T`,
- for a shared reference `&Vec<T>`, where the iterator returns shared references `&T`,
- and for `&mut Vec<T>`, where mutable references are returned.

[`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) is just a method in `Vec` to convert `Vec<T>` directly into an iterator that returns shared references, without first converting it into a reference. There is a sibling method [`iter_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut) for producing mutable references.

Comment: is there a reason to prefer doing
`for foo in vec` rather than `for foo in vec.iter()`?

Comment: That depend on what you are doing, and whether you still need `vec` after the loop. With `for foo in vec` each element of the vector is moved into `foo`, and the code in the loop can move it somewhere else, i.e. reuse it without cloning it, so if the elements are big that will be more efficient. It's also less to write, so you can always try `for foo in vec` first, and the borrow checker will remind you if that isn't OK.

Comment: So is it correct, that calling `for foo in vec` is synonymous to `for foo in vec.into_iter()`? And `for foo in &vec` is the same as `for foo in vec.iter()` and also `for foo in &mut vec` is the same as `for foo in vec.iter_mut()`?

Comment: @FlorianKusche That is correct!

Comment: If it is synonymous what is the most idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: @Jens The most idiomatic way is the simpler way, do not call methods that Rust will call for you. So, use `for x in vec` for consuming, `for x in &vec` for references, and `for x in &mut vec` for mutable references. And only use `.into_iter()`, `.iter()` and `.iter_mut()` explicitly when using in a fluent method chaining like `let data = vec.iter().filter(|x| x % 2 == 0).map(|x| x.to_string()).collect()`.