# Why are there two ways to iterate over a vector, IntoIterator and Iter?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have this example:

```
struct Foo { data: Vec<u32> }
impl Foo {
    fn get_list(&self) -> &Vec<u32> {
        &self.data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { data: vec![1, 2, 3] };

    // 1
    for it in foo.get_list() {
        println!("IntoIter {}", *it);
    }

    // 2
    for it in foo.get_list().iter() {
        println!("Iter {}", *it);
    }
}
```

As I understand it, in case (1) `&Vec` is converted to `IntoIterator`,
in case (2) we just use `Iter`.

1. Are the cases equal in terms of potential performance (what the compiler can do in optimization mode)?
2. If the cases are equal, why was `IntoIterator` introduced? Is it just to avoid writing `.iter()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case they are equivalent, because `get_list` returns a reference, so both `IntoIterator` and `iter` take a reference to the vector and return references to items.

If the vector were owned, it would be moved into `IntoIterator` (hence the name) and return owned items from the vector. `iter` on the other hand always takes a reference and returns references to items.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672845/in-rust-is-a-vector-an-iterator/36673695#36673695).

Answer (score 0):

1) Are cases equal in terms of potential performance (what compiler can do in optimization mode)? => No, it is not, it use references.

2) If cases are equal, why IntoIterator was introduced, just to not write .iter()? => It references to self.data and vector is not an iterator.