# Is there a trait supplying `iter()`?

Tags: iterator, rust, traits

Is there in Rust a Trait which supplies the `iter()` method? I only found the trait `IntoIterator`, which supplies `into_iter()`.

Just to be clear here: I do not want the `Iterator` trait, which supplies `next()`, but a trait which supplies `iter()`.

[ sidenote: Sometimes I'm very confused by the Rust libs. `Iterator` supplies `next()`, but `IntoIterator` supplies `into_iter()` (not supplying `next()` and for convention with moving), while `IntoIter` is a struct, that implements the `Iterator` trait (moving values). ]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672845/in-rust-is-a-vector-an-iterator/36673695#36673695

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, there is no trait that provides `iter()`.

However, `IntoIterator` is implemented on **references** to some containers. For example, [`Vec<T>`, `&Vec<T>` and `&mut Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) are three separate types that implement `IntoIterator`, and you'll notice that they all map to different iterators. In fact, `Vec::iter()` and `Vec::iter_mut()` are just convenience methods equivalent to `&Vec::into_iter()` and `&mut Vec::into_iter()` respectively.

```
fn foo(_x: std::slice::Iter<i32>) {}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    foo(v.iter());
    foo((&v).into_iter()); // iter() exists because this is awkward
}
```

If you want to write a function that is generic over containers that can be converted into an iterator that iterates over references, you can do so like this:

```
fn foo<'a, I: IntoIterator<Item=&'a i32>>(_x: I) {}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    foo(&v);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for this explanation. Combined with the link in the comment of starblue this is what I needed!

Comment: Why does rust not provide a trait with `iter()`? It sounds very useful, for example, if I want to have a struct that has a generic container as a member. `into_iter()` consumes the original container, and it would be useful to have a method that returns an iterator of references to the container without consuming it.

Comment: @kmaork What this answer is saying is that it's not necessary: if you call `into_iter()` on a *shared reference* to a container, you'll get an iterator over references, the same as calling `iter()`. There's no need for a trait providing `iter()` when `IntoIterator::into_iter()` already solves that problem. Maybe what you need is a [higher-ranked trait bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/234590)?

Comment: You say in your answer that "IntoIterator is implemented on references to some containers". Does that mean it is not implemented generically? If so, how is it possible to iterate over a generic container without consuming it?

Comment: Every container type `T` needs to implement `IntoIterator` for references to `T`, there's no way around that. When you call `into_iter()` on a `&T`, you are "consuming" the reference, but that doesn't consume the underlying container.