# Why does &str not implement IntoIterator?

Tags: rust

I am writing a container implementing the prefix tree in a generic way (key and value are generic parameters). Due to the nature of this data structure I need the key to have an iterator.

Essentially in accordance to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675949/is-there-a-trait-supplying-iter) the `IntoIterator` trait is responsible for this possibility but not all the structures implement it. For example `&str` and `String` do not implement it.

What should I do in this case when `IntoIterator` isn't implemented by the standard type?

An expected API is

```
let mut t1 = Trie::new();
t1.insert(String::from("this"), 1);

let mut t2 = Trie::new();
t2.insert(vec![1, 2, 3], 1);
```

Comment: You can write a wrapper type and implement the trait for it.

Comment: Also, Why does `string.iter()` not suffice?

Comment: @BernardoMeurer Please see the updated question. As far as I know there is no trait requiring implement `iter()`

Comment: @BernardoMeurer Besides the fact that there needs to be a trait for generics to work in this case, neither `str`, `&str`, `String`, nor `&String` appear to have an `iter()` method.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with `String` and `str` is that they have two types of iterators - `chars()` - iterator over UTF-8 chars and `bytes()` - iterator over bytes. That's why it's impossible to implement `IntoIterator` for these types. You have to create two wrappers (or pick one of them)

```
struct ByteString(String)
struct Utf8String(String)
```

and implement `IntoIterator` for them.

Comment: I think it would be a sensible default for `.into_iter()` to yield UTF-8 chars. You are still able to call `.bytes()` but 90% of the time you are using `&str` as UTF-8 text.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution, as stated in the comments, is to create a wrapper type:

```
use ::std::iter::IntoIterator;

struct StringWrapper<'a>(&'a str);

impl<'a> IntoIterator for StringWrapper<'a> {
    type Item = char;
    type IntoIter = ::std::str::Chars<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0.chars()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Raw str
    let wr = StringWrapper("test 1");
    for c in wr {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
    println!("-----");

    // Reference to raw str 
    let s = "test 2";
    let wr_s = StringWrapper(s);
    for c in wr_s {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
    println!("-----");

    // reference to String
    let owned_s = "test 3";
    let wr_s_owned = StringWrapper(&owned_s);
    for c in wr_s_owned {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```