# Why doesn't Vec implement the Iterator trait?

Tags: rust

What is the design reason for `Vec` not implementing the `Iterator` trait? Having to always call `iter()` on all vectors and slices makes for longer lines of code.

Example:

```rust
let rx = xs.iter().zip(ys.iter());
```

compared to Scala:

```scala
val rx = xs.zip(ys)
```

Comment: See also [In Rust, is a vector an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36672845/155423)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An iterator has an iteration state. It must know what will be the next element to give you.

So a vector by itself isn't an iterator, and the distinction is important. You can have two iterators over the same vector, for example, each with its specific iteration state.

But a vector can provide you an iterator, that's why it implements [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), which lets you write this:

```
let v = vec![1, 4];
for a in v {
    dbg!(a);
}
```

Many functions take an `IntoIterator` when an iterator is needed, and that's the case for `zip`, which is why

```
let rx = xs.iter().zip(ys.iter());
```

can be replaced with

```
let rx = xs.iter().zip(ys);
```

Comment: Great answer! Only thing I'm wondering right now: why does `xs.zip(ys)` work in Scala then? Is an iterator (state) automatically created in Scala? Or does its "list type" always contain an iterator state? Whatever solution Scala uses: why does Rust not use it?

Comment: Scala defines an Iterable trait for collections that may return a new iterator, yes. I'm not totally clear as to why it's not possible in rust to have a transparent iter() of self.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Because in Rust, the distinction between `iter()`, `into_iter()` and `iter_mut()` is important.

Comment: yes that would probably be messy if we'd have a mutable vec.

Comment: In Scala, `zip` is implemented through an extension trait ([`IterableOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/collection/IterableOps.html)) which `Vector` implements. A similar approach would be doable for Rust.

Comment: @Jmb but then, supposing you add the zip function and other ones to IntoIterator, how would you choose to call, for example, the iter() and iter_mut() functions of slices when starting your iteration chain ? It looks doable, yes, but it would probably be messy and hard to follow.

Comment: Note that Scala's `Iterable` trait is more or less equivalent to Rust's `IntoIterator` trait.

Comment: @DenysSéguret you're right. I'd say to only enable it for immutable iteration (using `iter`) and require an explicit call to `iter_mut` for mutable iteration.

Comment: Note that the same argument can be made for `ys` in `xs.iter().zip (ys)`: how do you choose to use `ys.iter()` or `ys.iter_mut()`?

Comment: For `ys`, we use `into_iter`. The reason is simple: `ys` is consumed, so other iterator kinds make no sense.

Comment: I don't know Scala, but I guess that a vector is an iterator because all the items are immutable reference types since it is functional. It does not have all the Rust ownership gymnastic.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios in Scala a vector isn't an iterator, it's an Iterable, which produces iterators on demand. The difference with Rust is that there doesn't need to be several types of iterators.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the design reason for `Vec` not implementing the `Iterator` trait?

Which of the three iterators should it implement? There are three different kinds of iterator you can get from a `Vec`:

1. `vec.iter()` gives `Iterator<Item = &T>`,
2. `vec.iter_mut()` gives `Iterator<Item = &mut T>` and modifies the vector and
3. `vec.into_iter()` gives `Iterator<Item = T>` and consumes the vector in the process.

> compared to Scala:

In Scala it does not implement `Iterator` directly either, because `Iterator` needs the next item pointer that the vector itself does not have. However since Scala does not have move semantics, it only has one way to create an iterator from a vector, so it can do the conversion implicitly. Rust has three methods, so it must ask you which one you want.

Comment: `into_iter()` is the one that consumes the vector; `drain` is different in that it only *empties* the vector.