# What is the idiomatic type signature for a function that accepts a generic type that must be a reference?

Tags: generics, types, rust

```rust
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn contains<'a, V, T, Q>(arr: V, value: &Q) -> bool
where
    T: 'a + std::cmp::PartialEq<Q>,
    V: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>,
{
    arr.into_iter().any(|v| v == value)
}

#[test]
fn test_contains_hash_set() {
    use std::collections::HashSet;

    let hs_str: HashSet<&str> = ["a", "b", "c"].iter().copied().collect();
    let hs_string: HashSet<String> = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()]
        .into_iter()
        .collect();

    let value_str = "b";
    let value_string = String::from(value_str);

    assert!(contains(&hs_str, &value_string));
    assert!(contains(&hs_string, &value_str));
    assert!(contains(&hs_string, &"a"));
}

#[test]
fn test_contains_vec() {
    let array_str = ["a", "b", "c"];
    let array_string = ["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()];

    let value_str = "b";
    let value_string = String::from(value_str);

    assert!(contains(&array_str, &value_string));
    assert!(contains(&array_string, &value_str));
    assert!(contains(&array_string, &"b"));

    //assert!(contains(array_string, &"b"));
    // ^^^ testing the compiler error for when there is no &
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62b27556f9ceb77141f7f48d2b7857dc))

Ignoring the `where` statement, I could read the type signature of `contains` as `contains(V, &Q) -> bool`. I would assume that, for whatever `V` is, its a concrete type that will be moved.

Including the `where` statement, `V` becomes a reference to something that can be turned into an iterator of `&T`s. Based on my previous assumption, I would want to make `V` into `&V`; however it would not compile as it becomes a reference to a reference of something.

If another developer did not know how `std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>` is implemented would they assume `V` is a concrete type that moves?
Is there any way to show in the type signature that `V` is expecting a reference?

As [trentcl explained in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747006/the-idiomatic-type-signature-for-a-generic-function#comment107478729_60747006):

> `V` isn't expecting a reference. `V` happens to *be* a reference in all the places you used it, but it doesn't have to be.

As the function `contains` type signature stands, could it be written in a more idiomatic way?

Comment: *Including the `where` statement, `V` becomes a reference to something* — it does not. *would they assume `V` is a concrete type that moves* — it does. *that `V` is expecting a reference* — it is not.

Comment: @Shepmaster So I do need to make it `&V`?

Comment: `V` isn't expecting a reference. `V` happens to *be* a reference in all the places you used it, but it doesn't have to be. [Here's an example where `V` is a `Vec<&&str>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f2d4689e1d9b31d2f682cf333c2d089)

Comment: No, I mean that your base suppositions are wrong. You pass in ownership of a value, not a reference. [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c45f18f16dd5929a377f7a2db73e2c5).

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423); [In Rust, is a vector an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36672845/155423). If so, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I don't think that answers my question. I wanted to enforce `V` to be a reference, but that was based on some incorrect assumptions about how Rust's generics work.